# mod_rewrite of localhost subfolder

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've ran into a htaccess problem on my localhost.

I have a subfolder called "*localhost/test*"

In that I want to make URL rewrite on the subfolder only. This means, that I want /localhost/test/something to be url_rewrite to /localhost/test/index.php?url=something

I hope it is possible.

Thanks.

Comment: no. you should NOT do that. `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` is the root dir of the **SITE**. Messing with its definition will only cause trouble later on if you start mixing/matching apps that expect the DOC_ROOT setting to reflect reality, not your subdir's fantasy.

Comment: Sorry, this is very vague. Please try to edit your question and make more clear what you are actually trying to do. Do not guess how this might be possible, just write what your situation is and what should happen.

Comment: I have now removed the doc_root part, and cleared about the mod_rewrite. Is it better now? :)

Answer (score 1):

add the following directive to .htaccess in **your subdirectory /test**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /test/

RewriteCond  !index\.php 
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Comment: Doesn't work. It is just saying, that the file can't be found - and there is an index.php-file, so that's weird.

Comment: Hey Amine, that doesn't work either. And my script requires that it is possible to use a / in the url-parameter.. So it doesn't fit anyway :-)

Comment: I've updated my answer to allow the forward slash, try to see what is the problem in the error log if it is not working.